# Entering entire paragraphs with \newcommand

Tags: macros, line-breaking

I'm trying to generate a few documents based on answers in an Excel sheet.
One of the questions in the excel sheet generates a \newcommand that is quite long.

For example:

```
\newcommand\articles{\colorbox{teal}{inhumande treatment (article 3), religious compulsion (article 9), and \his right for protec lorem ipsum dolor sit amet (article 9)\xspace}}
```

I then use this `\articles` to input this text piece in several places in my document.

However I cannot get it to "flow" like normal text and it will always place itself on one row, wheras I want it to flow just like any other text and break row if needed.

Any suggestions?

**Update**
The \colorbox prohibited the text to flow normally, after removal of the colorbox inside the \newcommand, everything worked as expected.

Comment: please show a small but complete example from your description `articles` (onot `\article`) should act the same way as `inhumande treatment (article 3), religious compulsion (article 9), and \his right for protec lorem ipsum dolor sit amet (article 9)\xspace`  so if somethig s preventing that from line breaking it is code not show and unrelated to `\newcommand`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Everything updated to match.
Answer added.

Answer (score 1):

Colorbox does not allow the text to flow naturally, when I removed the color box, it simply worked fine.

The reason for the colorbox was to debug and really make sure that we proofread all the variables in the text.

Comment: This answer references code not mentioned in the question so only you have seen, so it is not so useful to anyone else. Please fix the question to have an example of the problem,

Comment: Updated question to match.

Comment: Please add a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/140456) to your question. As it is only you can understand the question and the answer